# Могу ли я перенести значения из одной таблицы в другую в Postgresql одним запросом?

Tags: postgresql

Я хочу перенести 3 значения из одной таблицы в другую. Я делаю это тремя вложенными запросами. Могу ли я это делать одним запросом? То есть не писать 3 вложенных запроса?

```
UPDATE worker SET start = (SELECT em.start FROM employee em WHERE em.id = id); 
UPDATE worker SET end =   (SELECT em.end   FROM employee em WHERE em.id = id); 
UPDATE worker SET count = (SELECT em.count FROM employee em WHERE em.id = id);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE worker SET (start, end, count) = 
    (SELECT em.start, em.end, em.count FROM employee AS em WHERE em.id = id);
```

См. синтаксис [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-update.html).